# "Error: Cannot find module " error in Cygwin64 Terminal for wp-calypso in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, cygwin

I am trying to install wp-calypso with Cygwin64 Terminal in windows I have clone sucessfully and also added make module for Cygwin64 Terminal but still getting error for path when I am running "Make run"  command

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\cygdrive\c\Program'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\cygdrive\d\Angular\clones\wp-calypso\wp-calypso\bin\check-node-version'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
Makefile:81: recipe for target 'node-version' failed
make: *** [node-version] Error 1
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: There is a few things wrong with the paths that `make` is looking in. For one, `cygdrive` should be the only prefix, without the ``D:\``. I'm assuming there's also some kind of escaping issue and that `cygdrive\c\Program` is meant to be something like `cygdrive\c\Program Files`.

Comment: Do you know how can I fix this wrong path?